# Update DataSet From DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have read hundreds of threads on this but cannot figure this out.

Simple Code to set DataGridView datasource

```
try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(global::Saftrak.Properties.Settings.Default.TrackingConn))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = "SELECT PipeSize AS 'Pipe Size', InsulationSize AS 'Insulation Size', UnitWorkHours AS 'Unit Work Hours', LaborRate AS 'Labor Rate', UnitMaterialCost AS 'Material Cost Rate' FROM InsulationPricing WHERE InsulationTypesId = @iID";
                    command.Parameters.Clear();
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("iID", Globals.InsulationTypeId));

                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);                     

                    da.Fill(ds);


                    grd_Insulation_Pricing.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Ex.ToString() + "\n" + "\n" + Ex.Message + " " + Ex.Data);
            return;
        }
```

How can I get user edits on the datagridview to update to the Db. I have seen things about using the update() for the adapter, but I cant find that adapter outside of that method so I cant use something like ds.update() on the after cell change event because it would be out of scope. I'm just super unsure of how to do this. I'm sure this is a simple solution for someone. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

-Joseph

---------------------------------EDIT------------------------------------

I still dont have this figured out...

i have tried this

[Example1](https://khanrahim.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/insert-update-delete-with-datagridview-control-in-c-windows-application/)

and this

[Example2](http://forums.devshed.com/net-development-87/update-table-database-datagridview-winform-350445.html)

and neither one worked.

i have tried to call

```
da.Update(ds);
```

and always get

"The Name 'da' does not exists in the current context" Same for the 'ds'.

I have declared these outside the method to get them to be available and i get no errors, but nothing updates.

On Kenny's response, im not sure what i need to fill out for the command. Do i need to create an entire UPDATE sql statement for the datagridview. That doesnt seem right?

Please help

-joseph

Comment: In your update method, you again open another `SqlConnection`,  create another `SqlCommand`, and the call ds.update from within there. You are _not_ reusing the same `SqlConnection`/`SqlCommand` that you used to set datasource as shown in your code.

Comment: Thanks Kenny. That makes logical sense. I was looking at it from the wrong end.How would i tell the new dataset to pull the data from the datagridview